# trouble saving to intersect table following railscast

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes, attr-accessor

I'm trying to create nested attributes as outlined in this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/167-more-on-virtual-attributes?view=asciicast

In my example, I am trying to associate an activity to an image, so I have a structure of `activity -> activity_image -> image`.

When I save my activity, rails creates the activity and the image, but I'm not getting the intersecting table of activity_image being saved. Of course, I never actually tell rails to save this, but neither does the railscast I'm following.

Is there some way this is supposed to be defined in the models? What have I got wrong?

```
class Activity > ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :title, :description, :activity_image_url

    belongs_to :user
    has_many :activity_images
    has_many :image_urls, :through => :activity_images

    #validates_presence_of :title, :description, :url

  attr_accessor :activity_image_url
  after_save :assign_image

  private
  def assign_image
      if @activity_image_url
          self.activity_image_url = ImageUrl.find_or_create_by_url(@activity_image_url)
      end
  end
end
```